# select LEFT/RIGHT JOIN using WHERE and return NULL's

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to convert the following two **working** queries into a single query but everything
 I try just dies on me for various reasons.  My end result is to try to list all
 software on hand, and show which software is installed and which is not installed for the specific PC being queried.  For installed software, list the name, otherwise show NULL for the name.  I've tried some sub-select statements in the where clause which gave me a result without an error, but not the right result.  Any help is appreciated.

qry1

```
SELECT device_software.sw_id

FROM Software_device LEFT JOIN Device ON Software_device.d_id = Device.d_id

WHERE Device.d_id = 1;
```

qry2

```
SELECT Software.name, Software.sw_id, qry1.sw_id

FROM software LEFT JOIN qry1 ON software.sw_id = qry1.sw_id;
```

---

Device Table

```
------------------
| name  | d_id  |
------------------
| PC1   | 1     |
| PC2   | 2     |
| PC3   | 3     |
------------------
```

Software Table

```
------------------
| name  | sw_id |
------------------
| SW_a  | A     |
| SW_b  | B     |
| SW_c  | C     |
| SW_d  | D     |
------------------
```

Software_Device Table  (Many-to-many)

```
------------------
| d_id  | sw_id |
------------------
| 1     | A     |
| 1     | B     |
| 2     | A     |
| 2     | B     |
| 2     | C     |
------------------
```

Result Im looking for...
(Installed AND uninstalled software on PC1)

```
---------------------------------
| Sotfware  | pc_id |   name    |
---------------------------------
| SW_a      | 1     |   PC1     |
| SW_b      | 1     |   PC1     |
| SW_c      | NULL  |   NULL    |
| SW_d      | NULL  |   NULL    |
---------------------------------
```

I listed both mysql and sql tags because I don't think it matters, but just in case it does, i'm using mysql.

Comment: I'm going to add a .sql file in this post that includes all the data and tables to make this easier (at least for me). I won't be able to do this until this even though.  Thanks for the responses so far!

Comment: Here's the code to create the above tables/data.              http://tinyurl.com/8lnp879

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If RomanKonz answer is definitely close, just move the "where" to "on", letting the left join work appropriately.

```
select software.name as Software,
    device.d_id as pc_id,
    device.name as name
from software
    left join device_software
        on device_software.sw_id = software.sw_id
       and **device_software**.d_id = 1
    left join device
        on device_software.d_id = device.d_id
;
```

Comment: I'm getting an error `Unable to query local database Unknown column 'device.d_id' in 'on clause'` and it looks like it's because it doesn't know what to do with `...and device.d_id = 1...`.  If I take it out, the error goes away but obviously doesn't know which record I'm looking for.

Comment: it should have been device_software.d_id instead of device.d_id

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
   s.name AS software, 
   IF((SELECT COUNT(sw.d_id) FROM software_device sw WHERE sw.sw_id = s.sw_id AND d_id = 1) > 0, 1, NULL) AS pc_id, 
    (SELECT d.name FROM device d INNER JOIN software_device sw ON d.d_id = sw.d_id WHERE sw.sw_id = s.sw_id AND d.d_id = 1)  AS name
FROM 
   software s
ORDER BY s.name
```

**EDIT 2 :** Maybe not the most efficient/beautiful, but it works

Comment: This is close, it's returning software that's installed, but skipping uninstalled software.  So when querying PC1, I get two results, PC2 gives me 3 results.  Neither give me the NULL results (software not installed).

Comment: I'm not sure if you saw/downloaded the data and tables but if you did, i corrected the name of the software_device table.  If you haven't seen the link, it's tinyurl.com/8lnp879

Comment: This edit isn't giving me the error anymore but it's not giving me NULL values.  I played around with `AND` and `OR` but I wasn't able to get it to work.

Comment: This one works on my side, using the data you provided, @JonDoeCA

Comment: Great, thanks so much for your help!  I need to look into working more with sub-queries (I think that's what they're called).

Answer (score 1):

based on your requirements, this will give you the right result:

```
select software.name as Software,
    device.d_id as pc_id,
    device.name as name
from software
    left join device_software
        on device_software.sw_id = software.sw_id
    left join device
        on device_software.d_id = device.d_id
            and device.d_id = 1
```

just notes:
i prefer to put the primary keys as the first column in a table.
also i suggest to name your table in plural (devices)

Comment: I appreciate the comments.  This is close, it's returning software that's installed, but skipping uninstalled software. So when querying PC1, I get two results, PC2 gives me 3 results. Neither give me the NULL results (software not installed).

Comment: o right, the filter was wrong! i think it is correct now (assuming that you will query for one device)

Comment: I was thinking the same thing driving to work this morning.  However, now if I choose a PC with no software installed (PC3) I get the NULL's but if another PC has software installed, that software is left out of the query (SW_a & SW_b don't show up because it's installed on PC1 and PC2).

Comment: thanks robert, i've merged your advice. in Your version, you are using "device" before it is joined, i've corrected this (at least i hope it's correct, i can't test it here)

Comment: This version is listing all the available software now, but it's not singling out which is installed on 1 (or PC1) - they're all coming up as NULL.  I played around with parins "()" after the last `left join` but it didn't make a difference.  I appreciate all your efforts.  I spent 8 hours on this yesterday but wasn't able to combine the two querys. Does it maybe need a `SELECT` somewhere as it's `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: can you give us the create and insert statements to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Ok, this makes it a bit easier.  I just tried all the suggestions again to make sure it wasn't my translation.  Let me know if you're not able to retrieve the sql statements for some reason. tinyurl.com/8lnp879

Answer (score 0):

The following should do what you need:

```
select s.`name` as `Software`, d.`d_id`, d.`name` as `Device` 
from software s
      left outer join software_device sd 
          on sd.`sw_id` = s.`sw_id` and sd.`d_id` = 1     
      left outer join device d using (`d_id`)  
order by s.`name`
```

Comment: I'm getting an error "`Unable to query local database Unknown column 'sw_id' in 'from clause'`" which doesn't make sense.  The software ID is 'sw_id' for the software_device table.

Comment: After uploading the sql you provided and using the query above worked fine for me. However I have modified the query to enclose the field names in backticks for further clarification. You are using mysql correct?

Comment: I am using mysql.  Sorry, I should have been more clear in my original explanation.  What your query gives me is what I need with exception - I only want info for the specific PC being querried.  Look at the last example "Result Im looking for".  Your query gives me duplicates of software and all installations.  I appreciate the help though.

Comment: Ah, that's easy enough and the query has been modified.

Comment: We're on the same page, I tried that too, but what happens now is the the NULL's are no longer displayed.  I added code to recreated the data/tables to make it easier (tinyurl.com/8lnp879), but it looks like Robert and Billy were able to resolve it.  Thanks so much for your help!